# What to do when an answer is given in a comment

Tags: discussion

I have two questions where I got an answer, but in the comments:

[Was a duel between representatives of the fighting armies an accepted way to end armed conflicts in ancient time?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/was-a-duel-between-representatives-of-the-fighting-armies-an-accepted-way-to-end)

[Do dolphins have homosexual "blowhole" sex?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/do-dolphins-have-homosexual-blowhole-sex)

I commented to the person who wrote the comment and told them to give it as an answer and that I'll accept it, but they didn't do so for quite some time. Should I answer the question myself, or should I leave it "unanswered" until they'll write their answer as an answer.

- A similar case happened to me in SO, but there, when I told to write the comment as an answer and I'll accept it, the answerer did write an answer.

Comment: I've now answered the "duel" question, sorry about the delay!

Comment: I've got an answer for the first q. And posted an answer on the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’d say (personal opinion though):

Ping them in a comment and give them a reasonable time to write up an answer. If the don’t, write it yourself (and, if it’s the best in your opinion, accept it).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would take Jeff Atwood's advice posted as a comment to [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1128/41381) answer from a similar question on Programmers.

Comment: Seems that this question has jolted jozzas to move and post an answer to the dual question. I have opened a chat with the answerer of the dolphins question to remind him and I'll give him some time to post the answer. If he won't answer for a few days or tell me that he'll not answer at all, I'll answer it my self.